# Maven POM dependency and assembly

Tags: maven

I have a dependency in `pom.xml` with `type=pom`. In this dependency I have set of dependencies with `type=jar`.

Now I need to add some of these JARs to assembly
(include them to build with dependencySet -> includes).

If I set into `"include"` group and artifact of POM dependency, I get as result pom.xml in my build.

If I set into `"include" group and artifact of dependencies from external pom, I get an build error:

> Assembly is not configured correctly: One or more filters had unmatched criteria.

Has anyone seen this problem?

This is my main POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

This is my external POM:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

This is my assembly.xml:

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>output dir</outputDirectory>
        <includes>

            <include>apache:commons-configuration</include>
            <include>apache:commons-logging</include>
            <include>apache:commons-lang</include>
            <include>org.perf4j:perf4j</include>

            **Here I want to add slf4j-api and slf4j-log4j12 from external pom**
        </includes>
        <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
        <useStrictFiltering>true</useStrictFiltering>
        <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
```

---

This is main pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

This is external pom:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

This is assembly.xml:

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>output dir</outputDirectory>
        <includes>

            <include>apache:commons-configuration</include>
            <include>apache:commons-logging</include>
            <include>apache:commons-lang</include>
            <include>org.perf4j:perf4j</include>

            **Here I want to add slf4j-api and slf4j-log4j12 from external pom**
        </includes>
        <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
        <useStrictFiltering>true</useStrictFiltering>
        <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
```

Answer (score 0):

`useTransitiveDependencies` should be set to "true" instead of "false" in my `dependencySet`.